# Node js foreach done function

Tags: node.js, foreach, sequence

Insted of using setTimeout, what should I use after foreach complete?

```
app.post('/grid', function(req, res){
   getResults(req.body.idarray, function(callback){
       res.send(callback);
   });
});
function getResults(userIds, callback) {
    var totalresult = [];
    userIds.forEach(function (user) {
        sequence
            .then(function (next) {
                db.query('SELECT given FROM books WHERE user_id = ?', [user.userId], function (err2, result) {
                    if (err2) throw err2;
                    next(err, result);
                });
            })
            .then(function (next, err, books) {
                db.query('SELECT received FROM encycs WHERE user_id = ?', [user.userId], function (err3, result2) {
                    if (err3) throw err3;
                    next(err, result2, books);
                });
            })
            .then(function (next, err, books, encycs ) {
                Calculation(books, encycs, function (cb) {
                    totalresult.push(cb);
                });
                next();
            });
    });
    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log(totalresult);  // output ok.
        return callback(totalresult); // returning as expected
    }, 2000);
}
```

I dont know what totalresult.length is. So i can't check the length.

Comment: Check if you reaching third .then statement. If not, then you need to check it.

Comment: I didnt understand. can you show a mini example how to reach a .then statement?

Comment: You have three .then cases. First selecting *books*, second selecting *enycycs*, and the third statement perform some calculation and result is pushed into totalresult array. As far as I can see, this is the only place where you are populating it. The second thing to check, you are not returning your totalresult array anywhere in success branch of the callback, only on error. So, check whether you actually populating array and if I see correctly you are not returning it, therefore, return it whenever you need.

Comment: can you tell me where exactly do I have to return?

Comment: Not sure here, but as far as I can see you calling ```cb()```, that is not defined, and instead you should call ```callback(totalresult)``` instead of next(). If you update your code and write the context in which this method is used, it would be easier to help you. Until, it is only suggestions.

Comment: Sorry cb is cb2. edit mistake. I cant return callback instead of next() becuse still in looping. If

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, according to your use case you need to call callback somehow and pass totalresult into it, because that what your external code, code in the route expected.
To do that, you can call callback before calling next of the third .then statement. Like that.

```
        ...
        .then(function (next, err, books, encycs ) {
            Calculation(books, encycs, function (cb) {
                totalresult.push(cb);
            });
            callback(totalresult);
            next();
            //console.log(totalresult); //output OK.
        });
```

This might work.

**Update 1**

It is hard to follow with your code. Can't catch up the logic of it. I would propose you Promises approach. I prepared that solution, that might work. It might contain little errors, but it represents the main idea of what you are trying to achieve, and how it can be done.

```
app.post("/grid", (req, res) => {
    getResults(req.body.idarray)
        .then(data => {
            res.status(200).json(data);
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.error("Error occured", err);
            res.status(500).json(err);
        });
});

function getResults(userIds) {
    let promises = userIds.map(loadCalculation);
    //this will wait until all loadings are done
    return Promise.all(promises);
}

function loadCalculation(user) {
    //parallel loading of the books and encycs
    return Promise.all([loadBooks(user), loadEncycs(user)])
        .then(results => {
            let books = results[0];
            let encycs = results[1];

            let totalresult = [];

            Calculation(books, encycs, function (cb) {
                totalresult.push(cb);
            });

            return totalresult;
        });
}

function loadBooks(user) {
    return makeQuery('SELECT given FROM books WHERE user_id = ?', user);
}

function loadEncycs(user) {
    return makeQuery('SELECT received FROM encycs WHERE user_id = ?', user);
}

function makeQuery(query, user) {
    return Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        db.query(query, [user.userId], function (err, result) {
            if(err) {
                reject(err);
            } else {
                resolve(result);
            }
        });        
    });
}
```

Please, note that this is not really performant way to load the data from database, at least, I'm sure that you there is a possibility to load all the books and encycs with a single query, because you are using SQL, and it is really flexible language.

Comment: It didnt work and throw "Can't set headers after they are sent.". Becuase the place you said is still in loop. So, it will call callback againd and again until asyc.each finish.

Comment: async.each doesn't return anything. Let's start from the scratch. Why do you using sequence and async.each? Why not Promises with theirs chaining? Or even async await syntax of ES6/7? It is hard to understand such code.

Comment: I have no experience with promises and examples are difficult to understand for me. I changed my question. Can you look at that again? Thanks